# Forming a topology from a basis

Tags: general-topology

I'm having some trouble interpreting the topology on $X=\mathbb{Z}$ given by the basis $$\{\{n\}:n \textrm{ is odd}\}\cup\{\{n-1, n, n+1\} : n \textrm{ is even}\}.$$ For example, the set containing the singleton $\{\{1\}\}$ be an element of the topology, as it can be formed as an intersection of elements in the topology (eg. $\{\{1\}, \{3,4,5\}\} \: \cap \: \{\{1\}, \{7,8,9\}\})$. But how can we form this set containing only the singleton as a union of elements in the basis? Would there not always at least be one element looking like $\{n-1,n,n+1\}$ in each member of the topology?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you interpreted the basis as

$$\Big\{\{n\} \cup\{m-1, m, m+1\} : n \textrm{ is odd, } m \textrm{ is even}\Big\}$$

But in fact, it's

$$\Big\{\{n\}:n \textrm{ is odd}\Big\}\cup\Big\{\{m-1, m, m+1\} : m \textrm{ is even}\Big\}$$

I.e., everything in the left part is itself a basis element. In particular, $\{1\}$ is itself a basis element.

(Also, note that elements of the topology are always subsets of the space, not sets of subsets of the space. Even with your interpretation, the relevant elements in the topology would be $\{1,3,4,5\}$ and $\{1,7,8,9\}$, not $\{\{1\}, \{3,4,5\}\}$ and $\{\{1\}, \{7,8,9\}\}$.)

Answer (score 0):

$\{1\}$ is just a member of the base (not *basis*, that's a linear algebra thing), as $1$ is odd. So it's certainly in the topology.
Also, $\{1,2,3\}$ is in the base and the topology as it is of the form $\{m-1,m,m+1\}$ for $m$ even (here $m=2$).

So there are two types of set in the base: odd singletons and "even-centred tripletons"; and it's clear that these two types together cover all of $X=\Bbb Z$, and if any two intersect non-emptily it's in an odd singleton again (e.g. $\{1,2,3\}\cap \{3,4,5\}=\{3\}$ etc.) So the base is closed under non-empty finite intersections (so it *is* indeed a base for some topology, by the standard theorem for that).

A set $O\subseteq \Bbb Z$ is open is open in this topology iff for every *even* $m$ in $O$, $m-1$ and $m+1$ are also in $O$.

Comment: It's [not uncommon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) to call a base a basis.

Comment: @Christoph I'm against it. Base is the term all good topologists use.

Comment: I guess Munkres is not a good topologist then ;-)

Comment: @Christoph He does more weird non-standard things. Some nice educational examples though.